# Use NSManagedObject's own context property to delete it?

Tags: objective-c, nsmanagedobject

It may be kinda naive but I was wondering if it is correct to use the following statement to delete a managed object from the persistent store of Core Data:

```
[managedObject.managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
```

I ran the above in Xcode debugger - it didn't complain but the object's content was still there. Could it be that context was referenced through the object to be deleted, and thus causing a memory lock preventing deletion of the object?

Comment: Ok, if it is legal to use object's own NSManagedObjectContext property to delete it why not define 'deleteObject' method without any parameters and use object's context property? Further, I cannot think of a situation when you would have a NSManagedObject defined in one context but you would like to delete it from another - can someone give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

In regards to your content persisting, you still need to call save: on the context after deleting the object.

I can't answer specifically if you will have an issue by referencing the managedObjectContext in the managedObject as I usually use a 'DataManager' to manage my managedObjectContext.  Below is an example of a delete method that I used in one of my dataManagers:

```
- (void)deleteReport:(Report*)aReport inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context {
    if (aReport != nil) {
       if (context == nil) {
           context = self.managedObjectContext;
       }

       context.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy;
       [context deleteObject:aReport];

       NSError *error = nil;
       [context save:&error];
       if (error) {
           //NSLog(@"%@", error);
       }
   }}
```

EDIT: For clarification, the Report in this method is an instance of NSManagedObject, and the method takes NSManagedObjectContext as a parameter, because the application that it was pulled from supports the use of multiple contexts.